# My CSS background image is not showing

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am using the following css to display a background image on a page. However, all I get is a blank white background instead. I've been googling around, but can't figure out what is wrong with what I'm doing... any suggestions?

**CSS:**

```
#home_body {
    background: url(/resources/images/main_tree.png) no-repeat;
}
```

**Html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/main.css">
</head>
<body id="home_body">
    <div>
        <h1 class="main_heading">Welcome</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="home_nav">
        <nav>
            <ul id="main_menu">
                <li><a href="gv_shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="gv_gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="gv_about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="gv_news.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="gv_contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what is your html code ? did you have an error on console ( not founding the png for example )

Comment: Is the url relative to your CSS file? What does your network console (F12) say about the loaded image? Is it loaded correctly?

Comment: as @GolezTrol mentioned check your image path is relative to your your css file, otherwise give full http url of image....

Comment: set a border to your element to check that the width/height is big enough to display an image. A css background-image doesn't set a width/height to the element like an img would do. So perhaps its just a problem of container size

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, the url is relative, images on other pages are working, in fact, images are fine in general, I just haven't been able to get background images working.

Comment: Have you given height to that div?

Comment: @Miam84 The element with the background is the body.. if I set background-color or have any element within the body, they all show up.. it's just the background image that isn't showing. I also tried setting the backkground image on html tag to no avail

Comment: Tried: `url('../images/main_tree.png') no-repeat;` ?

Comment: @Totem are you sure that the url path is correct?

Comment: Ok, I figured the path was fine, as it's been working for images so far... but I moved the main.css from /resources/css/main.css to the root directory. I'm still confused, as images were working... but now the background image is also working.. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: hah, as soon as I answered. lol

Comment: Other images are working, but CSS images are not? Relative urls should be relative to the path of the CSS *url*. Make sure that is the case, and check the console to see if there are any 404 errors.

Comment: @GolezTrol No, all images were CSS, and all were working, since I guess the url must have been correct(it was relative). For some reason though, the background image wasn't working. I wasn't doing anything different with it that I can see. However, whatever was causing it was gone by the time I put the css file in the root dir. I don't remember changing anything else..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you copy paste the image URL into your browser does the image display?

2) Encase the CSS class image reference in single quotes.

3) Check your referencing, you're referencing the image from the root as `<root>/resources/images/main_tree.png` in the CSS but the HTML page is asking for a relative `resources/css/main.css` CSS file, *everything* should be root referenced (so all addresses on the page should start with a `/` ).

4) Check no other classes or CSS rules are being applied to the `<body>` element and are "overwriting" your background.

5) Try using `background-image` rather than the background shorthand. But remember to put the no-repeat in a new property:-

```
background-image:   url('/resources/images/main_tree.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: This includes the solution and pretty much covers all bases, thanks.

Comment: no worries, @Totem glad you got it sorted. It's handy to use things like Firebug or Google Chrome Inspector to do "live" assessment of CSS rules on the page, to establish where in the chain things are not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
#home_body {
background-image: url(/resources/images/main_tree.png) no-repeat;}
```

change css class to view image

Comment: that's not a class, that's a property.

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: background image should not show the repeat property.

Comment: @oshanikaushalya background works on its own for the image: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp